# Magento2: AddFotoramaVideoEvents is not a function on PDP?

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, console

I am getting error on PDP page in console for configurable product.
 while changing the attribute from PDP.it is showing belows error:
[image]

```
fotorama.js:953 GET http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/css/gallery.png 404 (Not Found)
    isHidden @ fotorama.js:953
    (anonymous) @ fotorama.js:3789
    waitFor @ fotorama.js:972
    (anonymous) @ fotorama.js:3788
    each @ jquery.js:370
    each @ jquery.js:137
    $.fn.fotorama @ fotorama.js:3781
    initGallery @ gallery.js:297
    initialize @ gallery.js:139
    (anonymous) @ wrapper.js:109
    UiClass @ class.js:49
    (anonymous) @ main.js:31
    execCb @ require.js:1650
    check @ require.js:866
    (anonymous) @ require.js:1113
    (anonymous) @ require.js:132
    (anonymous) @ require.js:1156
    each @ require.js:57
    emit @ require.js:1155
    check @ require.js:917
    (anonymous) @ require.js:1113
    (anonymous) @ require.js:132
    (anonymous) @ require.js:1156
    each @ require.js:57
    emit @ require.js:1155
    check @ require.js:917
    enable @ require.js:1143
    init @ require.js:774
    callGetModule @ require.js:1170
    completeLoad @ require.js:1564
    onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
    fotorama.js:953 GET http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/default/images/loader-1.gif 404 (Not Found)
    isHidden @ fotorama.js:953
    (anonymous) @ fotorama.js:3789
    waitFor @ fotorama.js:972
    (anonymous) @ fotorama.js:3788
    each @ jquery.js:370
    each @ jquery.js:137
    $.fn.fotorama @ fotorama.js:3781
    initGallery @ gallery.js:297
    initialize @ gallery.js:139
    (anonymous) @ wrapper.js:109
    UiClass @ class.js:49
    (anonymous) @ main.js:31
    execCb @ require.js:1650
    check @ require.js:866
    (anonymous) @ require.js:1113
    (anonymous) @ require.js:132
    (anonymous) @ require.js:1156
    each @ require.js:57
    emit @ require.js:1155
    check @ require.js:917
    (anonymous) @ require.js:1113
    (anonymous) @ require.js:132
    (anonymous) @ require.js:1156
    each @ require.js:57
    emit @ require.js:1155
    check @ require.js:917
    enable @ require.js:1143
    init @ require.js:774
    callGetModule @ require.js:1170
    completeLoad @ require.js:1564
    onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
    view.js:15 Value: Earn  10 Goshop Points
    8view.js:15 Value: undefined
    configurable.js:301 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).AddFotoramaVideoEvents is not a function
        at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._changeProductImage (http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.js:301:54)
        at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._changeProductImage (http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui.js:402:25)
        at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._configureElement (http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.js:272:18)
        at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._configureElement (http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui.js:402:25)
        at HTMLSelectElement._configure (http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.js:239:24)
        at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui.js:402:25)
        at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/jquery.js:5226:27)
        at HTMLSelectElement.elemData.handle (http://unicorn-stg2.local/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/jquery.js:4878:29)
    _changeProductImage @ configurable.js:301
    (anonymous) @ jquery-ui.js:402
    _configureElement @ configurable.js:272
    (anonymous) @ jquery-ui.js:402
    _configure @ configurable.js:239
    (anonymous) @ jquery-ui.js:402
    dispatch @ jquery.js:5226
    elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4878
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over ride below xml with below content:
When overriding the **catalog_product_view.xml**, it seems that the changes in ProductVideo are no longer applied – so the line has to be added like below

**app/code/Custom/Product/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/gKLgP1ns.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image.gallery" template="Custom_Product::product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\ProductVideo\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.video" after="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if the Magento ProductVideo module is enabled but the `gallery.phtml` block that it adds is moved or removed, you will get this error.

Kind of a silly dependency, I feel like this call to `AddFotoramaVideoEvents()` should be added to the `swatch-renderer.js` file via a mixin.

Anyway, my fix was to override the swatch-renderer.js file (copy it to `Magento_Swatches/web/js/` in my theme) and just add a wrapper to test if the method exists:

```
if (isInitial) {
    if ($.isFunction($(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents)) {
        $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I also had to add this check around the call to this method in the else branch as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below line in your catalog_product_view.xml by overriding it in your theme or module.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
 <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
     <block class="Magento\ProductVideo\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.video" after="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/> 
 </container>
```