# Getting TypeError: $(...).AddFotoramaVideoEvents is not a function in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7, swatches, configurable-swatches

The image gallery is not loading on product detail page getting an error like

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).AddFotoramaVideoEvents is not a function
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.updateBaseImage (swatch-renderer.min.js:50)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.updateBaseImage (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._loadMedia (swatch-renderer.min.js:24)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._loadMedia (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._OnClick (swatch-renderer.min.js:28)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._OnClick (widget.min.js:15)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (swatch-renderer.min.js:23)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:338)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery.min.js:311)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:332)
```

I followed this solution [Magento2: AddFotoramaVideoEvents is not a function on PDP?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209634/magento2-addfotoramavideoevents-is-not-a-function-on-pdp) also. but it does not helped.

Comment: where are you checking this thing on product detail page ? or in popup or somewhere else ?

Comment: In product detail Page.

Comment: May be some third party extension is creating this issue. Do you have Weltpixel Quickview extension ?

Comment: No, I don't have any third-party extension

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209634/magento2-addfotoramavideoevents-is-not-a-function-on-pdp